# Какие различия существуют между направлениями "Информационная безопасность" и "экономическая информационная безопасность"?

Tags: работа

В современных вузах существуют такие направления, как `"информационная безопасность"` и `"информационная безопасность в экономике"`. Если первое - это более общее направление подготовки, ориентированное на широкий спектр, то второе направление ориентировано, скорее, на безопасность в банковской сфере, в сфере финансов(как-то так).

Не могли бы вы на пальцах разъяснить, какие принципиальные и концептуальные различия существуют между этими двумя направлениями в современных высших образовательных учреждениях? Какие преимущества одного перед другим, если таковые есть? И может ли человек, отучившийся на втором направлении("инфобезопасность в экономической сфере"), заниматься информационной безопасностью в широком понимании этого слова?

**P.S** Стоит отметить, что я не имею ввиду возможность получения более приближенных к жизни знаний от одного из данных направлений - в конечном счете все сводится к личностному энтузиазму. Поэтому меня интересует лишь вопрос о возможных ограничениях на "уровне работодателя", применяемых к тем, кто в вузе готовился по направлению "информационная безопасность в экономической сфере"

Comment: В инфобезе люди с улицы не нужны. Если ты бородатый хакер, можно зарабатывать большие деньги, если просто интересующийся чувак, то увы.

Comment: @typemoon, как раз для того, чтобы подобные комментарии не всплывали, я выделил целый последний абзац. Я к тому, что с получением практических знаний в современных вузах и так все ясно...если ты полон энтузиазма, то вуз тебя многому не научит.

Comment: Для того чтобы хотя бы частично ответить на этот вопрос нужно смотреть учебный план каждой специальности. Одно могу сказать точно, выбирать специальность исходя только из перспективы будущего трудоустройства после ВУЗа крайне рискованно. За 4 года (тем более за 6 лет) может многое измениться.

Comment: Рекомендую "Компьютерную безопасность", где изучаются мат. методы защиты информации. Специальность очень интересная, фундаментально изучается алгебраическая теория чисел, алгебраическая геометрия и теория случайных генераторов в дополнение к стандартной программе матфака. Кроме этого в равных пропорциях с математикой на этой специальности есть программирование. Самая лучшая современная специальность. А с трудоустройством все равно будут проблемы, если человек не работает уже со второго курса. Никому не нужен разработчик лаб.

Comment: Работодатель может выкатить вообще любые требования, что в голову взбредет - то и захочет.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, всё различие в том, что даются дополнительные знания в предметной области (в данном случае, экономика). Эти знания могут потом пригодиться на всех этапах разработки: в сборе требований, проектировании, разработке и тестировании. Поскольку безопасность — вопрос важный, то и требования к подготовке — высокие.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не относится напрямую к программированию/алгоритмам

Answer (score 1):

В текущей постановке, ответа этот вопрос не имеет.

Для того чтобы хотя бы частично ответить на этот вопрос нужно смотреть:

- учебный план каждой специальности
- качество преподавания в ВУЗе
- преподавательский состав ВУЗа
- конкретных работодателей

А уж в разрезе "может ли человек, отучившийся на втором направлении .." - вообще **всё** зависит лично от вас.

Answer (score 1):

Для любого направления есть образовательный стандарт(ФГОС ВПО), который описания знания и навыки, которые вы должны будете иметь по окончанию образовательной программы. В этом списке значится только один стандарт, это `информационная безопасность`([описание специальности](http://www.moeobrazovanie.ru/specialities_vuz/informacionnaya_bezopasnost.html)), стандарта `информационная безопасность в экономике` там нет.

Значит, что это не специальность как таковая, а профиль подготовки. На практике, ВУЗ будет жертвовать одними необязательными перечнями знаний(которые по выбору) в пользу других. В данном случае добавятся экономические науки: экономика, бухучет и т.д. и т.п.

Вообще, каждый ВУЗ обязан предоставлять в открытом доступе программу обучения, которую вы можете посмотреть на сайте и определиться, в чем одно описание отличается от другого.